# ROS-Lunar Install on Debian Stretch: apt-key deprecation

Tags: ros-lunar, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a fresh install of Debian Stretch, I ran into an issue when using the ROS Lunar Debian Install instructions [[1](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian)]. The `apt-key` error output:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv -v --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.AaDAEF/gpg.1.sh -v --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: no running Dirmngr - starting '/usr/bin/dirmngr'
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ArFCphGHwI/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

After googling around a bit, it seems the Debian team has deprecated the use of `apt-key` [[2](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858238)]. Users say a workaround is to install the package `dirmngr` to keep using `apt-key`, but the Debian community recommends against this in Stretch and beyond.

Instead there is a Debian tutorial on adding trusted keys via `https` to a Stretch install [[3](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty)], which basically boils down to needing to retrieve keys using something like the following:

```
wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/deriv-archive-keyring.gpg https://deriv.example.net/debian/deriv-archive-keyring.gpg
```

My question: can I grab the gpg keys from the `ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net` via `wget`? Does OSRF have any other method for distributing gpg keys over `https`? It seems other users may have run into this issue, without knowing the root cause [[4](https://answers.ros.org/question/273191/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/)] & [[5](https://answers.ros.org/question/271419/unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/)].

[1] http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian 
[2] https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=858238 
[3] https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty 
[4] https://answers.ros.org/question/273191/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/ 
[5] https://answers.ros.org/question/271419/unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275824/ros-lunar-install-on-debian-stretch:-apt-key-deprecation/) by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 790 on 2017-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
Related question: #q264654.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
My answer to that question also mentions it's a work-around, and something more structural would need to be found.

As to `wget`ting the key: sure: the key is located at `https://packages.ros.org/ros.key`.

One issue with that: the certificate there is not valid for `packages.ros.org`, but that ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
.. could be solved.

Not using `apt-key` was how all install tutorials did it btw, before switching to `apt-key`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
The `ros-lunar-ros-core` Docker image just installs `dirmngr` and `gnupg2` at the moment ([here](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/ecf2b15a56686c6c7d3fc710c1753cfe3e5e9067/ros/lunar/debian/stretch/ros-core/Dockerfile#L6-L9)).

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2017-11-14**:
@gvhoorn I think it's fine for us to recommend using the workaround and install `dirmngr` and `gnupg2` for now. A a minimum, we need to update the Lunar Debian install guide to include this step, and we should open a ticket to address the issue properly. Where should I submit such a ticket?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
Hm. Not sure.

For the wiki I would either just edit the relevant pages, or perhaps if we'd want to discuss this first, post something on [ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues). Really a guess though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-14**:
Perhaps this could be discussed on ROS Discourse. That would probably be a better venue than the `roswiki` issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are lots of places you can get the ROS key.
The most visible is: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/ros.key

There is a bigger question of what is the best way to replace apt-key as debian is changing their recommended toolchain.

We used to wget from that url, but the best practices from the debian community was to use the key server instead of `wget` or `curl`.

We should find the new recommended best practice and switch our documentation and tutorials over to use that method. Which I think uses `dirmngr` but I haven't researched it too much. There are many people who spend a lot of time thinking about this we should find their discussions and leverage it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1